# Why is Qt Designer not displaying my network scan

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, network-programming, network-scan

I'm working on building a network detection application using python3. I'm working in Pycharm. I'm scanning using nmap. I'm having trouble displaying the scan results in QT designer. I've gotten as far as clicking my scan button however nothing displays as the scan completes. Here's my code below:

***Main page main.py***

```
`class Home(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Home, self).__init__()

        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        self.pages = {}

        self.home_page(Dashboard(self), 'dashboard')
        self.home_page(Stats(), 'stats')
        self.home_page(Details(), 'details')
        self.home_page(Data(), 'data')
        self.home_page(Threats(), 'threats')
        self.goto('dashboard')

  
    def home_page(self, page, name):
        self.pages[name] = page
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(page)

        if isinstance(page, PageWindow):
            page.gotoSignal.connect(self.goto)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def goto(self, name):
        if name in self.pages:
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.pages[name])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    home = Home()
    dashboard = Dashboard(home)
    dashboard.show()
    dashboard.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

***My scanner page scan_thread.py***

`

```
class ScanThread(QtCore.QThread):
    scan_complete = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScanThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def __def__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):

        nm = nmap.PortScanner()
        nm.scan(hosts='192.168.1.0/24', arguments='-p- --open -sV')
        self.results = []

        for host in nm.all_hosts():
            for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
                lport = nm[host][proto].keys()
                sorted(lport)
                for port in lport:
                    result = dict()
                    result['Host'] = host
                    result['Port'] = port
                    result['Protocol'] = proto
                    result['State'] = nm[host][proto][port]['state']
                    result['Address'] = ', '.join(nm[host][proto][port].get('addresses', {}).values())
                    result['OP System'] = nm[host][proto][port].get('osmatch', [{'name': ''}])[0]['name']
                    result['Product'] = nm[host][proto][port].get('product', '')
                    self.results.append(result)

        self.scan_complete.emit(self.results)`
```

My dashboard page dashboard_page.py

`

```
class Dashboard(PageWindow):
    def __init__(self, home):
        super(Dashboard, self).__init__()
        self.resultsTable = None
        self.scanThread = ScanThread(self)
        uic.loadUi('ui/dashboard.ui', self)
        self.home = home
        self.display_results([])

        self.statsMenu.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.goto_page('stats')
        self.detailsMenu.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.goto_page('details')
        self.dataMenu.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.goto_page('data')
        self.threatsMenu.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.goto_page('threats')
        self.scanBtn.clicked.connect(self.scan_host)

    def goto_page(self, event):
        self.goto(event)

    def scan_host(self):
        self.scanBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.scanBtn.setText('Scanning...')
        self.scanThread = ScanThread(self)
        self.scanThread.scan_complete.connect(self.display_results)
        self.scanThread.scan_complete.connect(self.update_scan_results)
        self.scanThread.scan_complete.connect(self.scan_finished)
        self.scanThread.start()

    def display_results(self, results):
        if not self.resultsTable:
            self.resultsTable = QTableWidget(self)
            self.layout().addWidget(self.resultsTable)
            self.resultsTable.setColumnCount(8)

        self.resultsTable.setRowCount(len(results))

        for i, result in enumerate(results):
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(result['Host']))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(result['State']))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(' '))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(result['OP System']))

            open_ports = 0
            closed_ports = 0
            scanned_ports = 0

            for port in result.get('ports', []):
                if port.get('state', '') == 'open':
                    open_ports += 1
                elif port.get('state', '') == 'closed':
                    closed_ports += 1

            scanned_ports = len(result.get('ports', []))

            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(open_ports)))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(closed_ports)))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(scanned_ports)))

        self.scanBtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.scanBtn.setText('Scan')

    def update_scan_results(self, results):

        self.display_results(results)

        # Display the new scan results
        for i, result in enumerate(results):
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(result['Host']))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(result['State']))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(' '))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(result['OP System']))

            open_ports = 0
            closed_ports = 0
            scanned_ports = 0

            for port in result.get('ports', []):
                if port.get('state', '') == 'open':
                    open_ports += 1
                elif port.get('state', '') == 'closed':
                    closed_ports += 1

            scanned_ports = len(result.get('ports', []))

            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(open_ports)))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(closed_ports)))
            self.resultsTable.setItem(i, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(scanned_ports)))

    def scan_finished(self):
        self.scanThread.scan_complete.disconnect(self.display_results)
        self.scanThread.scan_complete.disconnect(self.update_scan_results)
        self.scanThread.scan_complete.disconnect(self.scan_finished)
        self.scanThread.deleteLater()

    def clear_scan_results(self):
        self.resultsTable.clearContents()
        self.resultsTable.setRowCount(0)`
```

Comment: Typo: `display_results` is an attribute of `Dashboard`, not of `Home`: there is no `self.display_results` there. Note that this question has absolutely nothing to do with Qt Designer, the fact that you used it to create the UI is not relevant to what you're asking.

Comment: @musicamante. Thank you for the note. I removed the the scan function from the home page as it was redundant. Still not displaying my results.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not displaying". Is the table empty, or there's no table at all? I strongly suggest you to provide a valid [mre]: take your time to strip down your code to an example that exactly reproduces the issue and allows us to do the same, as right now we can only make assumptions since many aspects of your code are unknown to us. For instance, what is `PageWindow`? And, since the issue is about the results, the whole part adding other widgets (again, unknown to us) and switching pages, as they are completely irrelevant.